# Regexp big text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

**What I want to do:**

From

```
Sdqweq (65%) 3 : 2  (35%)   Dafsas
 1 ноября, 13:15     
Qrad (50%) 2 : 0  (50%)   Gherhgw
 29 октября, 13:00
....long file
```

To

```
{
  first: Sdqweq 
  firstscore: 3
  second: Dafsas
  secondscore: 2
  date: 1 ноября
}
{....}
{....}
```

Honestly  I did not understand much in regular expressions, but I dont know how to parse this text in another way. Is it real to build ?

I will be very grateful!

**UPDATE:**
update such part From

**UPDATE2**
When I try to use this `regex.exec(matches)` where `regex = /(.*?)\s*\(\d+%\)\s*(\d+)\s*:\s*(\d+)\s*\(\d+%\)\s*(.*)\s*(.*)/gm` and `matches = 'text from section'`
I have output like

```
Sdqweq (65%) 3 : 2  (35%)   Dafsas
     1 ноября, 13:15     , Sdqweq , 3 , 2 ,Dafsas,1 ноября, 13:15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple version of what do you want could be this:

```
/(Team\d+)\s*\(\d+%\)\s*(\d+)\s*:\s*(\d+)\s*\(\d+%\)\s*(Team\d+)\s*(.*)/gm
```

https://regex101.com/r/aS0uU9/5

---

Explanation:

Remember that:

- '\s' is a "White space character: Matches any space, tab or newline character."
- '\d' is any number
- '*' means zero or more ocurrencies
- '+' means one or more ocurrencies
- And the use of () delimits a group.

Then you have :

a.- First group starts with "Team" and is followed by 1 or more numbers. ie:
(Team\d+)

b.- .. followed by zero or more spaces. ie: \s*

c.- .. followed by '(', number (one or more ocurrences), followed by a '%' and followed by a ')'. ie: (\d+%)

d.- .. followed by zero or more spaces. ie: \s*

e.- Then we are looking for another group with a number with one or more ocurrences. ie: (\d+)

f.- .. followed by zero or more spaces. ie: \s*

g.- colon. ie: ':'

h.- .. followed by zero or more spaces. ie: \s*

i.- Then we are looking for another group with a number with one or more ocurrences. ie: (\d+)

....

z.- And almost at the end we look for one or more white space character '\s' (which includes the 'new line' character) and make a new group with all the following data (the date). ie: \s*(.*)

---

Edit:
To make the regex more generic:

```
/(.*?)\s*\(\d+%\)\s*(\d+)\s*:\s*(\d+)\s*\(\d+%\)\s*(.*)\s*(.*)/gm
```

https://regex101.com/r/aS0uU9/6

Here instead of pattern TeamNumber we are just looking for 'anything' (. means any character)

Comment: Missing first `/` , includes "(n%)" in results ; matches entire input string ?

Comment: WOW , holy sh... , great work, but I update part with `From` what I want to build

Comment: @Qwe _"but I update part"_ Why change original Question after 20+ minutes ?

Comment: @mayo Still returning "(n%)" included in results

Comment: @guest271314 I just removed that group ! Thanks !